# I cannot render the data from my db in React.js project "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, react-functional-component

I'm using Axios to get data from my API but when I try to render the state out I get an error of : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".

I used the same code for a previous component and it seemed to work.

Data looks like this:

```
[
{
"portfolio": {
"title": "Portfolio",
"subTitle": "Checkout my works"
},
"cv": {
"title": "Download my cv",
"subTitle": "Aviable in three languages"
},
"contact": {
"title": "Let's talk",
"subTitle": "Send me and e-mail"
},
"_id": "5eff2aefa386601f00c98b7d",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

code in App.js file :
I just used the state to pass data trough the portfolio component.

```
<Route path="/portfolio"  render={() => (<Portfolio title={state.header.portfolio.title} subTitle={state.header.portfolio} />)} />
```

Entire code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [state,setState] = useState({
    header:[]
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/metainfo')
    .then(res=>res)
    .then(data=>{
     // console.log(data.data)
   
     setState(prevState=>{
       return{...prevState,header:data.data}
     })
     
    })
  },[]);

  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />

        <div className="app-wrap">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render={Home} />
            <Route path="/portfolio"  render={() => (<Portfolio title={state.header.portfolio.title} subTitle={state.header.portfolio} />)} />
            <Route path="/cv" component={CV} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/footer" component={Footer} />
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Errors: [Image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd2eU.png)

Please help

Comment: Is the data really an array? So i assume there is a possibility that multiple header portfolio title could be fetched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of creating your own `setState`, I would change your state hook to be:

```
const [header, setHeader] = useState([]);
```

That is, assuming your data is an array. I'm not sure why it's an array, but that's what you've provided.

Next, your `useEffect` has an unnecessary `.then()` line in it. I would change it like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/metainfo')
    .then(res=>{
     // console.log(res.data)
   
     setHeader(res.data)
     // Use [...res.data] if necessary
    })
  },[]);
```

Finally, because your `header` state object is an array, you will need to reference it in your `Route` like so:

```
<Route path="/portfolio"  render={() => (<Portfolio title={header.length > 0 ? header[0].portfolio.title : ''} subTitle={header.length > 0 ? header[0].portfolio.subTitle : ''} />)} />
```

I've edited my answer to include that from blankart.

Comment: it would still result to an error since header is initially an empty array

Comment: Fair. I would combine what you've answered with mine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your error comes from the initial load of your Component. In order to fix this, change your `Portfolio` props

```
<Portfolio title={state.header.length > 0 ? state.header[0].portfolio.title : ''} subTitle={state.header.length > 0 ? state.header[0].portfolio.subTitle : ''} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after I edited that line of code as you said I'm getting these new errors https://imgur.com/a/a5OA23P

Comment: It seems like you forgot to add ```.subTitle``` property in your second props.